# How to convert slice of string to slice of float in Golang

Tags: go, type-conversion, slice

I am trying to convert a slice of string into float but the result isn't a slice. Is there a way to convert the elements within a slice of string to float64 to return a slice of float64?

```
func main() {

a := []string{"20.02", "30.01"}

fmt.Println("This is a single slice of string:", a)

for i, element := range a {
    element, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(element, 64)
    //This result converts each element to float64 but no longer holds them in a slice.
    fmt.Printf("%v, %v\n", i, element)
}
```

}

Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/LkNzgvDJw7u

Comment: I don't know why you have a slice of string, but if you recevied these from outside, like web request's params, cli options etc, you can define a struct to catch them.

Answer (score 5):

Create a slice of `float64` and append each element to it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    a := []string{"20.02", "30.01"}

    fmt.Println("This is a single slice of string:", a)

    // Creates a float64 slice with length 0 and capacity len(a)
    b := make([]float64, 0, len(a))

    for _, element := range a {
        element, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(element, 64)
        b = append(b, element)
    }

    fmt.Println(b)
}
```